# Android Material Ripple Layout ArrayAdapter setonitemclicklistener not working

Tags: layout, android-arrayadapter

I import this library to my android project. 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.1'
and I want to use in listview. ripple works fine but when I touch listview setinotemclicklistener not working. this is my code.

```
public class Jobs extends Activity {

ListView listOfJobs;
LinearLayout llBack;
//boolean[] bolSubGroup = {false,false,false,true,false,true,false,true,true,false,false,false,true};
ArrayList<String> lstID = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lstTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> lstSubggroup = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 String [] strTitle;
 Integer [] intSubgroup ;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.jobs);
    ListJobs();
     strTitle = new String[lstTitle.size()];
     intSubgroup = new Integer[lstSubggroup.size()];


    lstTitle.toArray(strTitle);
    lstSubggroup.toArray(intSubgroup);
    listOfJobs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstv_Jobs);
    LayoutAnimationController lac = new LayoutAnimationController(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Jobs.this,
            R.animator.in_from_right2), 0.8f); //0.5f == time between appearance of listview item
    listOfJobs.setLayoutAnimation(lac);
    listOfJobs.setAdapter(new JobsAdapter1(this, R.layout.jobs_single_row,
            R.id.txv_Jobs_SR, R.id.img_Jobs_SR, strTitle, intSubgroup));
    listOfJobs.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    llBack = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lil_Jobs_Top);
    llBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(20);
            finish();
        }
    });






    listOfJobs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

    });//*/
}
```

my array adapter

```
class JobsAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter  {
Activity context;
String[] items;
Integer[] arrows;
int layoutId;
int textId;
int imageId;

JobsAdapter1(Activity context, int layoutId, int textId, int imageId, String[] items, Integer[] arrows)
{
    super(context, layoutId, items);

    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.arrows = arrows;
    this.layoutId = layoutId;
    this.textId = textId;
    this.imageId = imageId;

}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtitems;
    ImageView img;
}

public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{


    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.jobs_single_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtitems = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txv_Jobs_SR);
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_Jobs_SR);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtitems.setText(items[pos]);
    if (arrows[pos] > 0)
    {
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrows_in);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.img.setImageDrawable(null);
    }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

my single row xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/ripple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/yellow_ShahreHarah"
    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
    app:mrl_rippleDimension="10dp"
    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:src="@drawable/arrows_in"
    android:id="@+id/img_Jobs_SR"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:id="@+id/txv_Jobs_SR"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_Jobs_SR"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/img_Jobs_SR" />

</RelativeLayout>

</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

and this is my main xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow_ShahreHarah"
    android:id="@+id/lil_Jobs_Top"
    android:layout_height="50dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/arrows_in"
            android:id="@+id/img_Jobs_Top" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:textDirection="rtl"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="گروه های شغلی"
            android:id="@+id/textView2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_left"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/lstv_Jobs" />
```

****************answer*****
i found answer

in single row xml file you have to write like this

```
<com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:ignore="UseCompoundDrawables"
app:mrl_rippleColor="#5b9bd5"
app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true"
app:mrl_rippleDimension="10dp"
app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
app:mrl_rippleDelayClick="true"
android:background="#00deeaf6"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lil_PIP_SR"
    android:background="#00deeaf6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/phone_home"
            android:id="@+id/img_PIP_HM_sr"
            android:layout_height="30dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try set `app:mrl_rippleInAdapter="true"` in your `com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout`. It works for me.